# re-created activity on bottom navigation view

Tags: android

Activity re-created on bottom navigation view item selected

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navlistner =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.na_home:
                        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        break;
                }
                return true;

            }
        };
```

Comment: `Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);` You're starting the same activity on clicking the home button of bottomnav. Maybe you want to start another activity? or add a fragment?

Comment: Every time when I am clicking home view item main activity recreate in several times in memory